# What is the difference between "Der Sessel" and "Der Stuhl"

Tags: difference, vocabulary

Simple question. Does anyone know a clear difference between the two words? Looking it up in a dictionary is not easy since both words translate to *chair* in English. The matter is further complicated by the special situation in Austrian German.

Comment: Did you look up the terms in a dictionary, and why didn’t that help you?

Comment: Perfectly valid question because it's not as easy as consulting a dictionary. Usage in Vienna is very different (what is called a Stuhl almost everywhere else is called a Sessel in Vienna), and it's tricky to come up with the right search terms to find this information on the web - especially when you are unaware that you are dealing with a regionalism.

Comment: Also, a *Sessel* is more likely to be called just a *chair* in English than it is to be called a *Stuhl* in (normal) German. This is why *chair* appears as a translation of both German words.

Comment: @Carsten S: Ich denke nicht, daß der Mindestaufwand für eine Frage durch jemand anderen als den OP „ersetzt“ werden kann oder sollte. Du hast auch eine Begründung, warum ein Wörterbuch dem OP vielleicht nicht geholfen hat oder hätte, frei erfunden; vielleicht hat er ganz andere Schwierigkeiten mit der Abgrenzung. – Abgesehen davon, daß z.B. LEO für _Sessel_ auch _armchair_, _easy chair_ angibt (und für _Stuhl_ nicht), gibt es noch andere Wörterbucharten. Wiktionary etwa hat sogar Fotos für [_Sessel_](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Sessel) und [_Stuhl_](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Stuhl).

Comment: @Hans Adler: Die regionale Bedeutung steht auch in Wiktionary. Und im Duden.

Comment: @chirlu: Wiktionary trägt in diesem Fall eher zur Verwirrung bei, denn die englische Version bietet *chair* als **einzige** Übersetzung von *Sessel* an. Der Duden liefert in diesem Fall aber in der Tat die vollständige Information, wenn man beide Wörter nachschlägt.

Comment: @chirlu und alle anderen close-Voter: So einfach, wie Duden und Wiktionary die Bedeutungen beschreiben, ist die Sachlage nicht. Besonders in Österreich werden diese Worte anders verwendet. Hans Adler hat in seiner Antwort das Wichtigste zwar schon gesagt, aber auch seine Antwort ist in dieser Hinsicht unvollständig, und daher würde ich gerne ebenfalls eine Antwort beisteuern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In German as spoken almost everywhere outside Vienna, the precise difference between *Stuhl* and *Sessel* is as follows. A typical *Stuhl* has the appropriate height for a dinner table. It has a back rest and may or may not have (firm) padding. It also may have unpadded arm rests. *Stuhl* is also the generic word for furniture that seats one person. A *Sessel* usually has lower seating than a chair. It always has a back rest and arm rests, all of which are usually padded. The padding is typically softer than that of a Polsterstuhl. Many but not all *Sessel* are manufactured as narrow variants of a *Sofa* or *Couch*. A *Sessel* may have a mechanism for reclining the back rest that may or may not include the appearance of a foot rest.

The basic correspondences for furniture seating one in standard German are roughly as follows:

- stool = Hocker
- stool with back rest (e.g. church stool) = Stuhl (e.g. einfacher Kirchenstuhl)
- unpadded chair = Stuhl
- padded chair = Stuhl, Polsterstuhl
- armchair = Sessel

Since this is in principle a simple question that can be quickly resolved by a dictionary, I am guessing that you have been exposed to a form of Austrian German. In eastern Austria, or at least in Vienna, people speak differently and tend to assume that all of Austria does. (The information is not easy to find with a web search due to large amounts of search results from furniture shops.) The correspondences in Vienna are roughly as follows:

- stool = Hocker (? - not sure about this)
- stool with back rest (e.g. church stool) = Sessel (e.g. einfacher Kirchensessel)
- unpadded chair = Sessel
- padded chair = Sessel (maybe Polstersessel is also used for this?)
- armchair = Polstersessel, Fauteuil

Note also that in German *Polster* means *padding*, but in Vienna it also has the (primary) meaning *cushion*.

PS: Some dictionaries offer *chair* as a translation not just of *Stuhl* but also of *Sessel*, without indicating a regional restriction. This is because in English, an arm*chair* is often referred to as just a chair, whereas German speakers are much less likely to refer to a *Sessel* as a *Stuhl*. Example:

- We have five chairs including the armchair. - Wir haben vier Stühle und einen Sessel.

Comment: Korrektur zur Situation in Österreich: Das Ding in der Kirche heißt nicht Sessel, sondern Bank. Ein Sessel ist nämlich ein Sitzmöbel für genau eine Person. Egal ob hart oder weich, und egal ob mit oder ohne Armlehnen. Es gibt aber auch Stühle in Österreich, das ist dasselbe wie ein Stuhl in Deutschland. »Sessel« ist nämlich der Oberbegriff für alle Einpersonensitzmöbel. Eine Ausnahme sind die Fauteuils, die nicht als Sessel bezechnet werden, weil sie eher als eine Variante einer Couch angesehen werden. (Couch = Diwan = Sofa) Und »at least in Vienna« kann man getrost durch »in Austria« ersetzen

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Ich meine aber tatsächlich nicht Kirchenbänke (heute Standard), sondern altmodische Kirchenstühle wie z.B. mit Google-Bildersuche nach "Kirchensessel Minoritenkirche Wien" zu finden. Viele haben eine ungewöhnlich niedrige, geflochtene Sitzfläche, eine ungewöhnlich hohe Lehne und sind aus sehr leichtem Holz. Auf Englisch heißen *solche* Stühle *[church] stools*.

Comment: Wenn ich in einer Kirche bin, dann nur um dort zu singen (als Mitglied eines Chores), dann sitze ich aber nicht, sondern stehe, und das meist direkt vor oder hinter dem Altar. Die Bestuhlung sehe ich dann nicht, denn wenn wir in einer Kirche singen, die die Hütte immer voll. Ich war sogar Mitglied des Kirchenchores der Minoritenkirche (Choro Antonio Salieri) und kenne die Minoritenkirche daher sehr gut. Aber die Sessel sind mir dort nie aufgefallen. Die Haupt-Bestuhlung besteht in dieser Kirche nämlich aus Bänken. Die von dir gemeinten Sessel müssen ganz hinten an der Wand stehen.

Comment: Wie gesagt, heute sind Kirchenbänke der Standard, wohl unter anderem weil die bei einer Panik sicherer sind. Kirchenstühle sieht man glaub ich vor allem noch in einigen großen historischen Kirchen. Zum ersten Mal sind sie mir im Straßburger Münster aufgefallen. (KIrchen kenne ich übrigens selber auch fast ausschließlich als Chorsänger.)

Answer (score 2):

Der Sessel is an armchair, der Stuhl is a chair. The difference is in the comfort level. Sessel implies a nice cushion (maybe leather) armrests, a not too low backrest, and so on.

(Just for completeness: Stool as in bar stool is der Hocker.)

See also [Sessel bei Leo](https://dict.leo.org/?lp=ende&lp=frde&search=sessel&searchLoc=0&relink=on&spellToler=standard&cmpType=relaxed) and [Stuhl bei Leo](https://dict.leo.org/?lp=ende&lp=frde&search=stuhl&searchLoc=0&relink=on&spellToler=standard&cmpType=relaxed).